# Remove extra white space from inside a C string?

Tags: c, string, whitespace

I have read a few lines of text into an array of C-strings. The lines have an arbitrary number of tab or space-delimited columns, and I am trying to figure out how to remove all the extra whitespace between them. The end goal is to use strtok to break up the columns. This is a good example of the columns:

```
Cartwright   Wendy    93
Williamson   Mark     81
Thompson     Mark     100
Anderson     John     76
Turner       Dennis   56
```

How can I eliminate all but one of the spaces or tabs between the columns so the output looks like this?

```
Cartwright Wendy 93
```

Alternatively, can I just replace all of the whitespace between the columns with a different character in order to use strtok? Something like this?

```
Cartwright#Wendy#93
```

**edit:** Multiple great answers, but had to pick one. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I may voice the "you're doing it wrong" opinion, why not just eliminate the whitespace while reading? Use `fscanf("%s", string);` to read a "word" (non whitespace), then read the whitespace. If it's spaces or tabs, keep reading into one "line" of data. If it's a newline, start a new entry. It's probably easiest in C to get the data into a format you can work with as soon as possible, rather than trying to do heavy-duty text manipulation.

Comment: That is something else I hadn't thought of. Hrrm.

Comment: If you know you're going to be reading a fixed number of columns, you could make a linked-list structure with named entries for each column. If you don't, you still might want to encapsulate the data in a linked list structure to keep track of the number of entries. Or you can use a dynamic array, but be warned that you'll have to pass around the size of the array everywhere you go (which you've probably been warned about a million times already if you've ever read anything about C).

Comment: I could always stand to be warned a few more times. C is not my strong point. I am a wussy scripting-language web programmer man.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with scripting languages. My native tongue is Perl and I'm currently stretching out my Python, but I enjoy C as well. It's good to learn C, because you learn to do things a new way. It almost made my Perl unreadable because I wanted to process text one character at a time with `getc()` for about an hour until I remembered how much easier it was to do it the way Perl wants you to.

Comment: Careful for buffer overflow using fscanf.

Comment: Echoing @Robert, use `fgets` in conjunction with `sscanf`.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a way with `scanf()` to limit the number of characters read into a buffer, but I can't find it. It should, however, be noted. You can even use `strchr()` to find whitespace in order to allocate the right amount of space for each buffer before you `sscanf()` the buffer.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `strtok()` directly? No need to modify the input

All you need to do is repeat `strtok()` until you get 3 non-space tokens and then you are done!

Comment: Happens to the best of us mate ;) see my comment on Alex Martelli's answer, I said the exact same thing lol

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I originally had a malloced workspace, which I though might be clearer. However, doing it w/o extra memory is *almost* as simple, and I'm being pushed that way in comments and personal IMs, so, here comes...:-)

```
void squeezespaces(char* row, char separator) {
  char *current = row;
  int spacing = 0;
  int i;

  for(i=0; row[i]; ++i) {
    if(row[i]==' ') {
      if (!spacing) {
        /* start of a run of spaces -> separator */
        *current++ = separator
        spacing = 1;
      }
    } else {
      *current++ = row[i];
      spacing = 0;
  }
  *current = 0;    
}
```

Comment: doing a malloc seems a bit heavy handed!

Comment: because you would allocate the memory how?

Comment: True that :) didn't think of that

Comment: It's feasible to just overwrite the existing row (just make sure to append the closing `'\0'`!-), I just thought I'd make things simpler for the OP. If the OP comments and/or edits (best: _both_;-) to ask for "no auxiliary memory to be allocated", I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, I give up (and, you know who you are, stop IRC'ing and IM'ing me), here's the no-extra-memory version instead -- hopefully just as simple;-). Happy now?-)

Answer (score 2):

The following code modifies the string in place; if you don't want to destroy your original input, you can pass a second buffer to receive the modified string. Should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *squeeze(char *str)
{
  int r; /* next character to be read */
  int w; /* next character to be written */

  r=w=0;
  while (str[r])
  {
    if (isspace(str[r]) || iscntrl(str[r]))
    {
      if (w > 0 && !isspace(str[w-1]))
        str[w++] = ' ';
    }
    else
      str[w++] = str[r];
    r++;
  }
  str[w] = 0;
  return str;
}

int main(void)
{
  char test[] = "\t\nThis\nis\ta\b     test.";
  printf("test = %s\n", test);
  printf("squeeze(test) = %s\n", squeeze(test));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* trimwhitespace(char *str_base) {
    char* buffer = str_base;
    while((buffer = strchr(str_base, ' '))) {
        strcpy(buffer, buffer+1);
    }

    return str_base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read a line then scan it to find the start of each column. Then use the column data however you'd like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_COL 3
#define MAX_REC 512

int main (void)
{
    FILE *input;
    char record[MAX_REC + 1];
    char *scan;
    const char *recEnd;
    char *columns[MAX_COL] = { 0 };
    int colCnt;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(record, sizeof(record), input) != NULL)
    {
        memset(columns, 0, sizeof(columns));  // reset column start pointers

        scan = record;
        recEnd = record + strlen(record);

        for (colCnt = 0; colCnt < MAX_COL; colCnt++ )
        {
          while (scan < recEnd && isspace(*scan)) { scan++; }  // bypass whitespace
          if (scan == recEnd) { break; }
          columns[colCnt] = scan;  // save column start
          while (scan < recEnd && !isspace(*scan)) { scan++; }  // bypass column word
          *scan++ = '\0';
        }

        if (colCnt > 0)
        {
            printf("%s", columns[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < colCnt; i++)
            {
             printf("#%s", columns[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
}
```

Note, the code could still use some robust-ification: check for file errors w/ferror; ensure eof was hit w/feof; ensure entire record (all column data) was processed. It could also be made more flexible by using a linked list instead of a fixed array and could be modified to not assume each column only contains a single word (as long as the columns are delimited by a specific character).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative function that squeezes out repeated space characters, as defined by `isspace()` in `<ctype.h>`.  It returns the length of the 'squidged' string.

```
#include <ctype.h>

size_t squidge(char *str)
{
    char *dst = str;
    char *src = str;
    char  c;
    while ((c = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isspace(c))
        {
            *dst++ = ' ';
            while ((c = *src++) != '\0' && isspace(c))
                ;
            if (c == '\0')
                break;
        }
        *dst++ = c;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return(dst - str);
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len > 0)
            buffer[--len] = '\0';
        printf("Before: %zd <<%s>>\n", len, buffer);
        len = squidge(buffer);
        printf("After:  %zd <<%s>>\n", len, buffer);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small improvment over John Bode's to remove trailing whitespace as well:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *squeeze(char *str)
{
  char* r; /* next character to be read */
  char* w; /* next character to be written */
  char c;
  int sp, sp_old = 0;

  r=w=str;

  do {
    c=*r;
    sp = isspace(c);
    if (!sp) {
      if (sp_old && c) {
        // don't add a space at end of string
        *w++ = ' ';
      }
      *w++ = c;
    }
    if (str < w) {
      // don't add space at start of line
      sp_old = sp;
    }
    r++;
  }
  while (c);

  return str;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char test[] = "\t\nThis\nis\ta\f     test.\n\t\n";
  //printf("test = %s\n", test);
  printf("squeeze(test) = '%s'\n", squeeze(test));
  return 0;
}
```

br.

Answer (score 0):

The following code simply takes input character wise, then check for each character if there is space more than once it skips it else it prints the character.
Same logic you can use for tab also.
Hope it helps in solving your problem. If there is any problem with this code please let me know.

```
    int c, count = 0;
    printf ("Please enter your sentence\n");
    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )  {
        if ( c != ' ' )  {
            putchar ( c );
            count = 0;
        }
        else  {
            count ++;
            if ( count > 1 )
                ;    /* Empty if body */
            else
                putchar ( c );
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please give a little explanation with your answer, rather than just dropping a block of code